# how to disable other buttons when a process is in execution in c#?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I run a time consuming process using background worker and i have disable all other buttons while the above said process is in execution. but when i try to disable other buttons,I get cross thread exception not valid error. how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you running a windows forms app or a wpf app?

Comment: Have you tried pasting the exception in a search engine and take a look at `(Begin)Invoke()`? Possible duplicate of [Cross thread UI component call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395167/cross-thread-ui-component-call)

Comment: if WPF: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is what you're looking for. But anyways, why on EARTH are you using a BkgdWkr?

Comment: You get the exception because you are trying to access a button on the main thread inside a background thread. Try to use Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Disable your buttons before starting background worker.

```
DisableButton(); // runs on UI thread
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then use [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handler to enable buttons:

```
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    EnableButtons(); // runs on UI thread
}
```