# Exception when closing Form (thread + invoke)

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have just started to learn about threads and methodinvoking in c#, but I have come across a problem which I couldn't find the solution of.

I made a basic C# form program which keeps updating and displaying a number, by starting a thread and invoke delegate.

Starting new thread on Form1_load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        t = new System.Threading.Thread(DoThisAllTheTime);
        t.Start();
  }
```

Public void DoThisAllTheTime (which keeps updating the number) :

```
public void DoThisAllTheTime()
  {
     while(true)
      {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
         {
           number += 1;
           MethodInvoker yolo = delegate() { label1.Text = number.ToString(); };
           this.Invoke(yolo);
         }
      }
  }
```

Now when I click the X button of the form, I get the following exception:

'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Can't update a deleted object'

While I actually did check if the form was disposed or not.

EDIT: I added catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) to the code which fixed the problem.
Working code:

```
  public void DoThisAllTheTime()
  {
     while(true)
      {
         number += 1;

         try {  
              MethodInvoker yolo = delegate() { label1.Text = number.ToString(); };
              this.Invoke(yolo);
             }
         catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
             {
              t.Abort();
             }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Well, the form got disposed after `(!this.IsDisposed)` was calculated, but before `this.Invoke(yolo);` was called. Welcome to the world of races.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Joker_vD How would I fix that? I assumed the check would be faster than the methodinvoke. It is also used on MSDN that way. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2 )

Comment: As others already said this is a race problem see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874728/avoid-calling-invoke-when-the-control-is-disposed

Comment: @Bart don't count on MSDN sample code being correct. Usually, it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `this.IsDisposed` is always out of date.  You need to intercept your form closing event and stop the thread explicitly.  Then you won't have to do that `IsDisposed` test at all.

There are many ways you can do this.  Personally, I would use the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, but if you want to keep your use of `System.Threading`, you should define a member variable `_updateThread`, and launch it in your load event:

```
_updateThread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoThisAllTheTime);
_updateThread.Start();
```

Then in your closing event:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _stopCounting = true;
    _updateThread.Join();
}
```

Finally, replace the `IsDisposed` test with a check on the value of your new `_stopCounting` member variable:

```
public void DoThisAllTheTime()
{
    MethodInvoker yolo = delegate() { label1.Text = number.ToString(); };
    while(!_stopCounting)
    {
        number += 1;
        this.BeginInvoke(yolo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding 't.abort();' to Form1_closing, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @Bart: Try setting a flag and then calling `t.Join();` to wait until the thread has recognized it.

Comment: I added catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) to it. This fixed the problem. I will update my question.

Comment: @Bart: As oefe said, that’s heinous! :D

Comment: And in fact, you don't need to define a new delegate at every stage of the loop -- that will make your garbage collector work a lot harder than it needs to.  Instead, add a method to your class an invoke that.

Comment: Since `Invoke` is blocking waiting for the main thread, there is a possibility for deadlock here if the `Form1_Closing` method is executed on the line `number += 1;`. The chance of deadlock goes up as more and more work is done in place of that line. I fixed this in my app by using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` since `BeginInvoke` will not block the thread from exiting and hence the `Join` will not block forever.

Comment: @WayneUroda, thanks for your reply. That was the trick missing for me. It made it finally work!

Comment: @WayneUroda -- thanks for the tip. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this override in your form class:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    t.Abort();
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: +1 For a nice solution.  To get more info: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874728/avoid-calling-invoke-when-the-control-is-disposed

Comment: @Alireza Thanks buddy. The answer is compatible with starter's skills that I got -and thought- from the question. But thanks really. Cheers

Comment: Normal scenario shutdown MUST NOT include calls to `Thread.Abort()`, `Application.Exit()`, etc. I've seen a bug caused by this -- transactions weren't rolled back because of a spurios `Environment.Exit()` inside of an `OnClose()` event handler.

Answer (score -3):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
}
```