# Invoke handle error on close despite multiple sanity checks

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I'm using this small utility function:

```
public static void Invoke(Control control, Action method)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        if (control.IsDisposed || !control.IsHandleCreated || !control.Created)
            return;
        control.Invoke(method);
    }
    else
        method();
}
```

Despite all of those sanity checks, when I close my application, a stray invoke always produces this error:

```
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
```

This, despite there clearly being a check to see if the handle is created... What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364116/avoiding-the-woes-of-invoke-begininvoke-in-cross-thread-winform-event-handling) which delves into Invoke'ing.  The problem you're experiencing is almost certainly down to a control disappearing between the if(...) return; and the Invoke doing its thing.

Comment: That was indeed helpful. When I replaced all usage of Invoke with BackgroundWorker (whose progress report event had to be somewhat abused to achieve the desired behaviour) it runs without complaint.